# Where to put Global variables in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, global-variables

I used to put Global variables in environment.rb with my Rails 2.3.8 application such as:

```
MAX_ALLOWD_ITEMS = 6
```

It doesn't seem to work in Rails 3. I tried putting it in application.rb and that didn't help.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What you are asking about is not variable, but a constant, what means: it cannot be set from within application. I was misleaded here by search engine because the wrong term is used here.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you have already tried restarting your server as Ryan suggested, try putting it in your `application.rb` like this:

```
module MyAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    YOUR_GLOBAL_VAR  = "test"
  end
end
```

Then you can call it with the namespace in your controllers, views or wherever..

```
MyAppName::Application::YOUR_GLOBAL_VAR
```

Another alternative would be using something like [settingslogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic).  With settingslogic, you just create a yml config file and a model (Settings.rb) that points to the config file.  Then you can access these settings anywhere in your rails app with:

```
Settings.my_setting
```

Comment: I created a plugin inspired by settingslogic, but it does not require you to create a class for the settings.  You only have to include the yml file and the class is created dynamically when the server starts.  Here is the repo:  https://github.com/cowboycoded/yettings

Comment: It is not variable, but a constant, what means: it cannot be set from within application. I was misleaded here by search engine because the wrong term is used here.

Answer (score 7):

I usually go with application_helper.rb
This is what it looks like:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def my_global_variable 
    my_global_variable = "Helloworld!"      
  end
end
```

Then I can put in my_global_variable anywhere as a function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are truly defining it in *config/environment.rb* like you say, the only way I can duplicate your problem is by running up a server using `rails server`, **then** putting in the variable to *config/environment.rb*, referencing it in a view or controller somewhere and then trying to load that specific part of my application.

If I stop the server and start it again and again try to access that view or controller then it works. I reckon you just haven't restarted your server.

Answer (score 1):

I normally create inside config/initializers/ a yaml (yml) file with all the global site settings. 
remember to restart the server each time you change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the solution of adding variables to environment.rb would in fact work in Rails3 - to be specific, if you haven't defined the variable inside a module definition like so:

```
module MyConfig
  Max_ints = 5
end
```

you won't be able to just use Max_ints, if you just include it as a bare definition. Or at least that's what I found happened when I experimented with this. I also think the suggestion to use the initializers/ folder is possibly a better solution in terms of ease of use. See [Permanent variable in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490985/permanent-variable-in-rails?lq=1)