# Global Variables in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to put Global variables in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598785/where-to-put-global-variables-in-rails-3)

Is it possible to set Site-Wide Global Variables in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice

```
$my_global_var = "I am very bad variable!"
```

- http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html
- http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_summary2.html

Comment: As far as I know, this is bad practice, **because it might not be thread safe**.

I am not entirely sure of the details, but I do know that with several server-setups, the global variables will not only leak trough threads (`$user = current_active_user()` will give unexpected results, because $user is changed for all active threads). But might even leak trough to other apps, allthough I recall this only being a problem in mod_ruby. 

I have never investigated this deeply, hence my vagueness. I simply heeded the many warnings telling me "never ever to even consider it" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use general Ruby syntax $var_name, but I don't know any case when global variable is a best approach.