# How do you add a variable to the global scope? (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm trying to do some unit tests, and my `current_account_permissions` variable is undefined when running the tests. (works fine when the server is running).

It's similar to `current_user` in that it's available everywhere, except tests apparently.

Is there a way I can add the variable to the global scope?

Maybe something like `ENV["current_account_permissions"] = whatever` but not having to use the `ENV[]` notation to retrieve the variable?

Comment: Where is `current_account_permissions` defined? Define `global` :) I guess it means it is known in all controllers?

Comment: seconding what @nathanvda said, which means that the global variable is most likely **not** the correct solution.

Comment: consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598785/where-to-put-global-variables-in-rails-3

Comment: @nathanvda yeah, it's availabel in all the controllers / helpers / views. I'ts defined in lib somewhere where current_user and current_account are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming here, but without any code it is hard to tell, that somehow the `current_account_permissions` is mixed in into the `ApplicationController`.

I would also assume that the `current_account_permissions` is a method, which should do something like

```
def current_account_permissions
  @current_account_permissions ||= current_user.get_current_account_permissions
end
```

So if that is the case, all your controller tests would run fine as dandy. In your view tests however, you will have to stub the `current_account_permissions` because when testing there is no controller context.

Hope this helps.