# How declare a global variable in ROR3.0 within a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

hi i m new to ruby on rails please let me know is it possible to declare a variable within the function/method

```
def fun1
  #initialized a global variable 
end  

def fun2
  #access value   
end
```

is it possible get value of a variable declared in fun1 function by fun2 function

Answer (score 1):

To create a truly *global* variable, use `$`:

```
def fun1
  $foo = 'bar'
end  

def fun2
  puts $foo
end
```

Here `$foo` is available outside the class instance once `fun1` has been called.

As noted in the first comment, this [should be used sparingly](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html):

> They are dangerous because
>   they can be written to from anywhere. Overuse of globals can make
>   isolating bugs difficult; it also tends to indicate that the design of
>   a program has not been carefully thought out.

What you're probably asking for is an instance variable, which uses `@`:

```
def fun1
  @foo = 'bar'
end  

def fun2
  puts @foo
end
```

Here `@foo` is available anywhere in the current instance of the class, again once it has been declared by calling `fun1`.

See for example [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope) on the various variable scopes in ruby.

Comment: It is important to note that the use of global variables, `$variable_name` are highly discouraged, especially more so among Ruby developers.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, it would be better if you could share your actual scenario for what you need to define a global variable from a function. There might be a better, manageable, DRY approach for your solution.

**Secondly**, apart from the answer from "Thilo", here are few references showing the usage of global variables for **rails** in different situations. Not just for ruby. You need it for rails right?

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110947/1160106
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3600860/1160106