# Can I make a flash like hash in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a ruby/rails newbie and need to make a hash which can be manipulated anywhere in the rails application and can be accessed by all views just like the flash[:notice] hash. Is this possible?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598785/where-to-put-global-variables-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def block
    @block ||= {}
  end
  helper_method :block
end

block[:foo] = "FOO"
block[:foo] #=> "FOO"
```

However, what you are trying to do is normally done with the help of [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Any key/value pair can be stored in flash.
for example,

```
     flash[:email] = 'abc@yahoo.com'
     flash[:username] = 'abc'
     flash[:xyz] = 'xyz'
```

These values can be accessed any where in controllers and views, just like `flash[:notice]` and `flash[:error]`